# Convert array of NSData to array of UIImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, core-data, uiimage

Here is the thing. At a point in my app, I want to show on a CollectionView the photos stored in Core Data (yes, I use External Storage). To get only the photos in my Entity I do the following:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"SmallThing"];
[fetchRequest setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
[fetchRequest setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"smallphoto", nil]];
self.photos = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil]mutableCopy];
```

That seemed to work fine, it returns the data for the photos and store it on the array. Then I created a method to convert it to UIImage so I could store on another array as following:

```
- (NSMutableArray *)convertDataToImage:(UIImage *)image {
for (NSData *data in self.photos) {
    image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
    [self.images addObject:image];
}
return self.images;
}
```

When I get to the line `image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data` it crashes and I get the following error:

```
[16697:2367280] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSKnownKeysDictionary1 length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fae0c117cc0'
```

I don't know what else I can do. Any ideas ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This means `data` is really an `NSKnownKeysDictionary1`, not an `NSData` object. `self.photos` is not an array of `NSData` like your code is assuming.

Comment: Yes, sir, you were quite right. Now I'm having problem on adding the image to the images array. For some reason it's returning null

Answer (score 1):

You are explicitly telling the fetch request to return dictionaries with the line:

```
[fetchRequest setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
```

Which means the array returned by `executeFetchRequest...` contains `NSDictionary` objects, with key-value pairs corresponding to the properties you specified.

Your code in `convertDataToImage` should be along the lines of:

```
for (NSDictionary *dictionary in self.photos) {
    NSData *data = dictionary[@"smallphoto"];
    ...
}
```

If you specified a different property to fetch other than `smallphoto` you would of course substitute that string there as appropriate.

Comment: Very well! The error disappeared, but the image is returning nil therefore the images array is nil as well.

Comment: I mean the array is returning nil. It's like the images are not being added to it

Comment: @LeonardoRangel I don't understand what you mean by that. Which value is `nil` and when? What keys & values do the `NSDictionary`s in the fetched results have?

Comment: I figured it out, it was a stupid thing I was missing, I never initialized the images array so it was always nill. It's working just fine now. Thank you very much